# How to compile with libquantum library

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, compiler-errors, linker

I'm currently learning this quantum computing C/C++ library called [libquantum](http://www.libquantum.de). After performing a successful installation and confirming it by trying some demos that came along the source code, I tried writing my own program (**main.cpp**).

```
#include<quantum.h>
 
 int main(){
         quantum_reg qr;
         quantum_delete_qureg(&qr);
}
```

I tried to compile this program with:

> g++ main.cpp -lquantum

but it failed:

> /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc6aR9vu.o: in function `main': main.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to` quantum_delete_qureg(quantum_reg_struct*)' collect2: error: ld
> returned 1 exit status

I also tried:

> g++ main.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lquantum

considering libquantum.so is there, but same error

What is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

The library is C and seems to have no awareness of C++. The link error has a type in it, which suggests that the linker is trying to link it in C++ mode.

Try putting a `extern "C"` around the include:

```
 extern "C" {
     #include<quantum.h>
 }

 int main(){
         quantum_reg qr;
         quantum_delete_qureg(&qr);
}
```

What is going on? To implement function overloading, C++ encodes type information in function symbol names so they no longer match up with the C function names in the binary library, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling

Comment: thank you, this works and this is the first time I'm aware of this C/C++ lib difference.